# How to get all the books based on the user that is logged in with angular frontend and express backend?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am working on a practice application where A user signs into an angular frontend and after sigining in and being verified is navigated to a type of profile page where all of the books in their collection is stored.

This is my backend route:

```
router.get('/books/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  let token = req.headers['jwt'];
  if(token) {
    authService.verifyUser(token).then(user =>{
      if(user) {
        let userId = req.params.id;
        models.books.findAll({
          where: {userId: userId, Deleted: false }
        }).then(books=> {
          console.log(todos);
          res.status(200).json(books);
        })
      }else {
        res.status(400).json({message: 'Nope not gonna happen'})
      }
    })
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({message: 'Internal malfunction!'})
  }
 });
```

This is my service call:

```
getBooks(userId: number): Observable<Book[]> {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("access-token");
  let header = new HttpHeaders().set("jwt", token);   
  return this.http.get<Book[]>(`${this.api}/books/${userId}`, {headers: header});
}
```

This is my component:

```
export class AdminUserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
user: User;
books: book;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private bookService: BookService,
    private router: Router

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBooks();
  }
  getBooks(): void {
    const userId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('userId');
    this.userService.getTodos(userId).subscribe(books => books = books);
  }
}
```

When the user logs in I am directing them to the details page where all of the books in their collection will be displayed.  Everything is working up until the point where the books should be retrieved.  Instead of displaying the books for that user, I am getting select books from books where userId = 0 and nothing returned.  Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On your component `const userId = +`, that `+` is a typo? I don't think that could be the error, but anyway.

Comment: No, if the + isn't included angular tries to read the statement as a string instead of a number.

Comment: Have you debugged (even with console.log())?? Just to know where that `userId` value is lost.

Comment: Try subscribing to route params, instead of using the snapshot. Like `this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => { const userId = params.get('userId'); this.userService..... })` Maybe the snapshot is not refreshing....

Comment: Thank you so much Sergio.  Greatly appreciated.  As I stated earlier, I am learning as I go and all of this is very new to me, so please forgive my ignorance. Be blessed.